# Angular datatables: sort non-textual data

Tags: angular-datatables

Is there a way to create custom sorting for a column containing non-textual data?

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

I would like to sort by the icon symbol.

P.S. The both icons are shown using `ng-if` and a boolean value from the dataset.

Edit: I'am using the Angular way of displaying data.

```html
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptionsLoginHistory" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefsLoginHistory"
               class="table table-striped row-border hover"
               width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Success</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="entry in entries">
                <td style="width: 10%;">
                    <i ng-if="!entry.failed" class="fa fa-check" style="color: green;"></i>
                    <i ng-if="entry.failed" class="fa fa-times" style="color: red;"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: please show exactly how you render the table.

Comment: @davidkonrad I updated my question.

Comment: @davidkonrad Would you be so kind and look at my another datatables question, since you probably know this library very well? Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032004/angular-datatables-searching-for-a-specific-html-class-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several different ways to achieve what you want. Considered your setup I believe the easiest would be to create a special `orderType` that return a value based on which `fa-*` classes the `<i>` elements is rendered with :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['fa-classes'] = function(settings, col)  {
  return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map(function(td, i) {
    return $('i', td).hasClass('fa-check') ? '1' : '0';
  })
}
```

Will give all `<i class="fa fa-check">` order `1`, any other `0`. This could also be a `switch { .. }` returning multiple different order values.  Use it like this :

```js
$scope.dtColumnDefsLoginHistory = [
   DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('orderDataType', 'fa-classes')
];
```

small demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/8S5f2MR331CiNBYYfDQf?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

Add an orderBy filter:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="entry in entries orderBy : 'failed'  "> 
    <td style="width: 10%;">
       <i ng-if="!entry.failed" class="fa fa-check" style="color: green;"></i>
       <i ng-if="entry.failed" class="fa fa-times" style="color: red;"></i> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `orderBy` along with dataTables is not a good idea. At best you will end up in rows visually rendered different than the underlying internal row structure.  It would be the correct answer on a DOM table without dataTables.