# Angular-DataTables - Searching for a specific html-class value

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I would like to filter datatable table by a attribute class name. Here is some image. The idea is, to click on the star icon near the table header to show only entries, which are favorite.

[image]

I already tried some options how to achieve this, but it doesn't work. As I understood, I should define some `keyup`-listener for the star icon in the header. Here is some code I used by now:

```
$scope.dtInstanceCallback = function (dtInstance) {
                var table = dtInstance.DataTable;

                // Apply the search
                table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                    if ($('i', table.column(colIdx).header())[0] != undefined) {
                        $('i', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup', function () {
                            if ($scope.showFavorites) {
                                table
                                    .column(colIdx)
                                    .search('fa-star', false, false, true)
                                    .draw();
                            } else {
                                //here drop the search by the star value drop search
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
```

The `$scope.showFavorites` is just a variable containing `true` or `false`. I switch it's value when I `ng-click` the star icon. It's initially initialized with `false`:

```
$scope.showFavoriteOnly = function () {
                $scope.showFavorites = !$scope.showFavorites;


            };
```

A little problem is to no use the smart search, because the both icons (full star and empty star) differentiate only by a letter: `fa-star` and `fa-star-o`.

The `.search` function has been taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23931504/3402092.

**Little Edit**: I marked the column as search type string:

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('orderDataType', 'fa-classes').withOption('sType', 'string')
```

So I can use the search-input to find `fa-star-o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling, that what you really are looking for is a [**custom filter**](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html). A custom filter is a customized search / filter that can be either dynamic (as a regular search) or permanent, which mean that subsequent searches will be a subset of that custom filter, until it is removed.

I imagine you have columns with content like `<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>` in the first column. You can implement two custom filters that filters out rows with `fa-star` / `fa-star-o` this way :

```
$scope.starFilter = function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {         
      return $(data[0]).hasClass('fa-star')
    }    
  )
  $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop() //remove this line to make the filter persistent
}

$scope.starOFilter = function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {         
      return $(data[0]).hasClass('fa-star-o')
    }    
  )
  $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop() //remove this line to make the filter persistent
}
```

Here invoked by a button click

```
<button ng-click="starFilter()">star filter</button>
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/hUSZ0XpRDZPjERsr0vF5?p=preview**

The very great advantage of this approach is that you can make the filter persistent. If you not `pop()` the filter then subsequently user searches will be a subset of the filter subset itself, for example within "favorites", all rows with a `fa-star` icon.

Comment: @Sirion, Thank you for accepting the answer! It was a long shot with custom filter, but I think you will like it more. Using it myself a lot to for example filter rows between date range, and then the user can search within that range, or as you filtering certain types of row out.

Comment: your solutions works, but not in my case. I load icons from DB as html, and when I inspect `data` the column with the icon is a large empty string. So I decided to access column on another way. But somehow, I cannot get the filtering and sorting work together. I created a plunker with my case, could you please have a look at it? http://plnkr.co/edit/PRu8bZI0vO1ocgvjW9oA?p=preview. Somehow this simple functionality took already a lot of my time.

Comment: @Sirion, can it wait to tomorrow? It is 03.16 here in DK,  and I have been drinking alcohol (it is summertime in DK). I will look into it tomorrow (sunday)

Comment: It's not a problem at all.

Comment: Ok, I made it work now. I update the plunker, if you will want to have a look at it:  http://plnkr.co/edit/PRu8bZI0vO1ocgvjW9oA?p=preview . P. S. jQuery is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I my case the data[index] was empty (don't really know why). But I managed to get it working with following function:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function (settings, data, index, rowData, counter) {
      return $(rowData[0]).hasClass('fa-star');
   }
);
```

I replaced `data` with `rowData` and managed to access the html-object.

The desired functionality is shown here:
**[plnkr.co/edit/PRu8bZI0vO1ocgvjW9oA?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/PRu8bZI0vO1ocgvjW9oA?p=preview)**

Comment: Looks great, and as user you have the intuitive feeling that you could filter by clicking on the ★ icon.